# Adding text below text box

Tags: matlab, plot, octave

I have a `text` item on one of my plots, placed at a certain location, with a certain orientation:

```
th=text(x,y,'some text','HorizontalAlignment','right','rotation',rot);
```

Based on its position (`get(th, 'Position')`), or any other property, is there any way to compute the lower bound of its bounding box? I want to place another text just below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `Extent` property. You will probably need to tweak the alignments depending on what you're after, but something like this:

```
th = text(x,y,'some text','HorizontalAlignment','right','rotation',rot);
ex = get(th,'Extent');
text(ex(1),ex(2),'Text Below')
```